# Different names for HbA1c

Tags: diabetes, endocrinology, type-2-diabetes, glycated-hemoglobin-hba1c

Am a data analyst working on healthcare data analysis. I came across the below terms in my source data from the hospital system. I did a google [search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=vItAYJf9OsmH9QOWqo_QDA&q=glycated%20hb&oq=glycated%20hb&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyFAgAELADEIoDELcDENQDEOUCEIsDMhQIABCwAxCKAxC3AxDUAxDlAhCLAzIUCAAQsAMQigMQtwMQ1AMQ5QIQiwMyFAgAELADEIoDELcDENQDEOUCEIsDMhQIABCwAxCKAxC3AxDUAxDlAhCLAzIUCAAQsAMQigMQtwMQ1AMQ5QIQiwMyFAgAELADEIoDELcDENQDEOUCEIsDMhQIABCwAxCKAxC3AxDUAxDlAhCLAzIUCAAQsAMQigMQtwMQ1AMQ5QIQiwMyFAgAELADEIoDELcDENQDEOUCEIsDUABYAGC-ri1oAnACeACAAZMCiAGTApIBAzItMZgBAKoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQq4AQPAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiXy_ChjpbvAhXJQ30KHRbVA8oQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) and found that they all are the same

```
Glycated HB        %           
Glycated HB, POCT  %           
HbA1c, IFCC        mmol/mol 
HbA1c, NGSP/DCCT   %
```

Am I right to understand that all these indicates `HbA1c` measurement only and they are just different names with different representations (`%` or `mmol/mol`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, HbA1c is glycated Haemoglobin ([Hb](https://www.diabetes.co.uk/what-is-hba1c.html))  the [A1c](https://www.webmd.com/diabetes/guide/glycated-hemoglobin-test-hba1c) bit refers to the type of Haemoglobin.

POCT is Point of Care Testing. (See https://dx.doi.org/10.1177/1932296814538940

IFCC is International Federation of Clinical Chemistry and Laboratory Medicine (https://www.ifcc.org/) a standardisation program for HbA1c testing

DCCT is the Diabetes Control and Complications Trial. (See https://www.niddk.nih.gov/about-niddk/research-areas/diabetes/blood-glucose-control-studies-type-1-diabetes-dcct-edic)

NGSP is an organisation looking to standardise HbA1c testing (http://www.ngsp.org/).

> When the NGSP began in 1996 it was originally called the “National Glycohemoglobin Standardization Program”.  As the program grew and became international in scope the official name was shortened to the acronym.

Comment: So, its all the same. Get it. Upvoted

Comment: Hi @chris. If you have time, can help me with this post?  https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/25854/what-does-unspecified-mean-in-diagnosis-descriptions